# Google Ad Manager (DFP) Deliver Blank/Empty Creative

Tags: javascript, ads, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I would like to have a line item that delivers 5 banners and rotates through them. So far, so good. That is easy.

Now I do not want to annoy the user and would like to have some sort of advertisement pause. Like every 1 of 5 times, NO AD is displayed.

I tried creating an empty creative and call `collapseEmptyDivs(true)`, but I cannot create an empty creative. Does anyone have an idea on how to create a blank/empty creative in DFP

Answer (score 0):

according to the GPT documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_collapseEmptyDivs)) about collapsEmptyDivs(true) :

> Enables collapsing of slot divs so that they don't take up any space on the page when there is no ad content to display.

This means the ad slots will collapse only if there is no ad to display. Therefore, no need to create an empty ad on Google Ad Manager Interface. 
To make it work properly, collapseEmptyDivs will need to be declared on your page when you define the GPT tag options (in head scripts). Here is a sample :

```
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>
<script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    // Start: GPT Adslot Definition
    googletag.defineSlot('gamNetworkId/siteName/sitePage', [[300,250], [300,600]], 'pave').addService(googletag.pubads());

    //generic options
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().setCentering(true);
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true);
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
```

On Google Ad Manager interface : you just have to apply a capping on your current line item to make sure the users will not see "too much" ads.